# Convolution of binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

As part of a (SE) problem I've been working on, I came up with this expression:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^M\binom{M-1+i}{i}\binom{M+i}{i}
$$
I'd like to get a closed form for this, but after a considerable amount of time searching my references and online sources (not to mention the time I've spent bashing this into other equally opaque equivalences), I've come up empty. Does anyone have a clue? I'll be happy to link to the original if asked, but the expression more or less tells the story.

Comment: Have you tried computing the sum for small values of $M$ to see if there's a pattern?  If there is a pattern (and you can guess it) then you may succeed with induction...

Comment: When I plug in M=1, 2, 3, 4, 5 I get (respectively) 3, 25, 273, 3321, 42878

Comment: @TravisJ. Of course. Back to you: did you notice that these values were divisible, respectively, by 3, 5, 7, 9, and 11?

Comment: No I hadn't noticed that.  It continues, though: $13|575107$, $15|7921245$, and I didn't check beyond that... this is cool.  If you don't mind my asking, which SE problem are you looking at?

Comment: @TravisJ [this one](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43404), which should really have been asked here anyhow. As I indicated, I have a couple of other equivalent formulations, one of which involves the *squares* of binomial coefficients.

Comment: I lied, I tried it for $M\in [30]$ and each one is divisible by the next odd number...

Comment: Looks like a fun problem.  It was asked here actually: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319271/counting-number-of-different-matrices it looks like it comes from some online competition (see comments in the linked question).  Funny that I just reviewed the close vote on this question (while writing the python script for yours...)

Comment: Actually carrying out the division gives you https://oeis.org/A129763

Comment: It doesn't report a closed form that I can tell.

Comment: @TravisJ: Ha ha, no, I meant that OEIS doesn't report a closed form expression for that series.

Comment: @BrianTung, oh... that makes a lot more sense... I was confused.

Comment: @BrianTung. Too bad. I considered generating functions, but I probably would have never come up with the OEIS one. Ah, well. As my dissertation advisor said, "some things are just ugly".

Comment: @Rick: The asymptotics aren’t bad, though (if you don’t mind exponential explosions, anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\sum_{i\leq M}\dbinom{M-1+i}{i}\dbinom{M+i}{i}=\frac{1}{\left(M-1\right)!M!}\sum_{i\leq M}\frac{\left(M-1+i\right)!\left(M+i\right)!}{i!}\frac{1}{i!}=$$ $$=\frac{1}{\left(M-1\right)!M!}\sum_{i\leq M}\frac{\left(M\right)_{i}\left(M+1\right)_{i}}{\left(1\right)_{i}}\frac{1}{i!}$$ so it is the partial sum of the hypergeometric function $$\frac{1}{\left(M-1\right)!M!}\,_{2}F_{1}\left(M,M+1;1;1\right).$$

Comment: And it looks like that'll be the best we can do. Not exactly a closed form, but certainly tidy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate representation of the sum.

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$S_M =
\sum_{q=0}^M {q+M-1\choose M-1} {q+M\choose M}.$$

Introduce
$${q+M\choose M} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{q+M}}{w^{M+1}} \; dw.$$

and furthermore introduce
$$[[0\le q \le M]]
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^M}{z^{q+1}} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{z^{M+1}-1}{(z-1)z^{q+1}} \; dz$$

which controls  the range so we may  let $q$ go to  infinity to obtain
for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{z^{M+1}-1}{(z-1)z} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{M}}{w^{M+1}} 
\sum_{q\ge 0} {q+M-1\choose M-1} \frac{(1+w)^q}{z^q}
\; dw\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{z^{M+1}-1}{(z-1)z} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{M}}{w^{M+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1-(1+w)/z)^M}
\; dw\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{z^{2M+1}-z^M}{(z-1)z} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{M}}{w^{M+1}} 
\frac{1}{(z-(1+w))^M}
\; dw\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{z^{2M}-z^{M-1}}{(z-1)^{M+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{M}}{w^{M+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1-w/(z-1))^M}
\; dw\; dz.$$

Extracting the residue at $w=0$ we obtain
$$\sum_{q=0}^M {M\choose M-q} {q+M-1\choose M-1} \frac{1}{(z-1)^q}.$$

There are two contributions to the outer integral here, the first is
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=1}
\sum_{q=0}^M {M\choose q} {q+M-1\choose M-1} 
\frac{1}{(z-1)^{q+M+1}} \sum_{p=0}^{2M} {2M\choose p} (z-1)^p
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^M {M\choose q} {q+M-1\choose M-1} 
{2M\choose M+q}.$$

The second is
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=1}
\sum_{q=0}^M {M\choose q} {q+M-1\choose M-1} 
\frac{1}{(z-1)^{q+M+1}} \sum_{p=0}^{M-1} {M-1\choose p} (z-1)^p$$
and this is easily seen to be zero.

The product of the three binomials is
$$\frac{M!}{q!\times (M-q)!}
\frac{(q+M-1)!}{(M-1)! \times q!}
\frac{(2M)!}{(M+q)!\times (M-q)!}.$$

which yields
$$\frac{M}{M+q}
\frac{(2M)!}{q! \times (M-q)! \times q! \times (M-q)!}.$$

which finally gives for the sum
$$M {2M\choose M}
\sum_{q=0}^M \frac{1}{M+q} {M\choose q}^2.$$

Comment: Thanks, Marko. This was one of three different expressions I came up with. It's good of you to put it on record.

Answer (score 0):

If the “$-1$” were missing from the first binomial, we'd get [OEIS A$112029$](http://oeis.org/A112029), which converges

asymptotically to $\dfrac{4^{2n+1}}{3\pi~n}~,$ and –at the same time– we also have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{A_{112029}(n)}{a_n}=2$, where

$a_n$ is our sequence. So, in conclusion, $a_n\sim\dfrac{2^{4n+1}}{3\pi~n}$ . It does not appear to possess a meaningful

closed form expression, and even the simpler afore-mentioned [OEIS](http://oeis.org) sequence seems to lack one.

Answer (score 0):

**Remark.** The Iverson  bracket that was used in  the first answer is
not quite appropriate  as the infinite series it  was substituted into
does not converge in a neighborhood of zero.

The appropriate form of the Iverson bracket here is
$$[[0\le q\le M]] =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{z^{q}}{z^{M+1}}\frac{1}{1-z} \; dz.$$

This yields for the sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{M+1}}\frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{M}}{w^{M+1}} 
\sum_{q\ge 0} {q+M-1\choose M-1} (1+w)^q z^q
\; dw\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{M+1}}\frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{M}}{w^{M+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1-z(1+w))^M}
\; dw\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{M+1}}\frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{M}}{w^{M+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1-z-zw)^M}
\; dw\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{M+1}}\frac{1}{(1-z)^{M+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{M}}{w^{M+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1-zw/(1-z))^M}
\; dw\; dz.$$

Extracting the residue at $w=0$ we obtain
$$\sum_{q=0}^M {M\choose M-q} {M-1+q\choose q} \frac{z^q}{(1-z)^q}.$$

Substituting this into the integral in $z$ yields
$$\sum_{q=0}^M {M\choose M-q} {M-1+q\choose q}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{M-q+1}}\frac{1}{(1-z)^{M+q+1}} \; dz$$

which is 
$$\sum_{q=0}^M {M\choose M-q} {M-1+q\choose q}
{M+q+M-q\choose M+q}
\\= \sum_{q=0}^M {M\choose q} {M-1+q\choose M-1}
{2M\choose M+q}.$$

This is the same  as what we obtained in the first  version and we may
continue as before.

**Addendum.**

We  can  also evaluate  this  using the  negative  of  the residue  at
$w=(1-z)/z$ of the inner integral. This requires the derivative
(use Leibniz' rule)

$$\frac{1}{(M-1)!}\left(\frac{(1+w)^M}{w^{M+1}}\right)^{(M-1)}
\\ = \frac{1}{(M-1)!}
\sum_{q=0}^{M-1}
{M-1\choose q} \frac{M! \times (1+w)^{M-q}}{(M-q)!}
(-1)^{M-1-q}
\frac{(M+M-1-q)!}{M! \times w^{M+1+M-1-q}}
\\= (-1)^{M-1} \sum_{q=0}^{M-1} {M\choose q} (1+w)^{M-q}
(-1)^q {2M-1-q\choose M} \frac{1}{w^{2M-q}}.$$

Evaluation yields
$$(-1)^{M-1} \sum_{q=0}^{M-1} {M\choose q} \frac{1}{z^{M-q}}
(-1)^q {2M-1-q\choose M} \frac{z^{2M-q}}{(1-z)^{2M-q}}.$$

Re-write the double integral as follows:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2M+1}}\frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{M}}{w^{M+1}} 
\frac{1}{((1-z)/z-w)^M}
\; dw\; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^M}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{2M+1}}\frac{1}{1-z}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{M}}{w^{M+1}} 
\frac{1}{(w-(1-z)/z)^M}
\; dw\; dz.$$

Substitute the evaluated derivative  into this integral to get
$$- \sum_{q=0}^{M-1} {M\choose q} 
(-1)^q {2M-1-q\choose M} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{M+1}}\frac{1}{(1-z)^{2M+1-q}} \; dz
\\ = - \sum_{q=0}^{M-1} {M\choose q} 
(-1)^q {2M-1-q\choose M}
{2M-q+M\choose M}
\\ = - \sum_{q=0}^{M-1} {M\choose q} 
(-1)^q {2M-1-q\choose M}
{3M-q\choose M}.$$

We still need the value of  the residue at infinity of the integral in
$w$ using the following formula:

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} h(z)
= \mathrm{Res}_{z=0} 
\left[-\frac{1}{z^2} h\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right]$$

which in the present case yields
$$- \mathrm{Res}_{w=0}
\frac{1}{w^2} \frac{(1+1/w)^M}{1/w^{M+1}} 
\frac{1}{(1-z/(1-z)/w)^M}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{w=0}
\frac{1}{w} (1+w)^M
\frac{w^M}{(w-z/(1-z))^M}
\\ = - \mathrm{Res}_{w=0}
(1+w)^M
\frac{w^{M-1}}{(w-z/(1-z))^M}.$$

This is zero  by inspection and since the residues sum  to zero we may
conclude that the sum has the alternate representation
$$\sum_{q=0}^{M} {M\choose q} 
(-1)^q {2M-1-q\choose M}
{3M-q\choose M}.$$